# Add an writer to a spreadsheet via "Google Document List API"

Tags: google-docs-api, google-apps-script

I'm writting a script in Google Aps (GAS) and I need to add a user(/writer) (administrator of the domain) to a spreadsheed of a another user.

The script is running/invoked under administrator privilegies.

First I use "Google Apps administrative access to impersonate a user of the domain" and I get a list of his documents (spreadsheets) and I get the Id of the documents.

var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("docs");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken? 
      (...)

This part is working fine and get the desired Id's.

Now, I want to add to myself (administrator@example.com) to this document

I'm trying this:

```
var optAdvancedArgs = {
"contentType": "application/atom+xml",
"method": "POST",
"headers": {  "GData-Version": "3.0" }, 
              "oAuthServiceName": "docs", 
              "oAuthUseToken": "always",
           };
```

var url_set = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/" + user + "/private/full/document:" + matriu2[0][6] + '/acl/user:administrator@example.com'

var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_set, optAdvancedArgs);

"user" is the owner of the document, the active user (Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId()) and "matriu2[nm][6]" is the Id of the document.

This don't work,

Any ideas ?

Sergi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending an hour of time, here is what I got
This function will share the document to yourself (Domain administrator).
You may change other parameters in xml to have read, write permission etc

```
function shareDocumentToMe(){
  var base = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
  var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('docs', base);
  var writerID = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  fetchArgs.method = 'POST';
  var rawXml = "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gAcl='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007'>"
      +"<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' "
      +"term='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessRule'/>"
      +"<gAcl:role value='writer'/>"
      +"<gAcl:scope type='user' value='"+writerID+"'/>"
      +"</entry>";
  fetchArgs.payload = rawXml;
  fetchArgs.contentType = 'application/atom+xml';
  var url = base + 'user@yourdomain.com/private/full/'+yourDocumentID+'/acl?v=3&alt=json';
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs).getContentText();
  Logger.log(content);
}

//Google oAuth
function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

I have posetd the same code on my Google Site.
You can have a look here.
https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/urlfetch-and-oauth

Answer (score 0):

I would never have found this. Thank you very much.

I modified the following  (var url = ...):

```
'user@yourdomain.com/private/full/'
```

by
     `user + '/private/full/'`

where

```
user = Session.getActiveUser (). getUserLoginId ()
```

and also in the `googleOAuth_` I put my domain values​​:

```
oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey ("mydomain.com");

oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret ("xXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXx");
```

And it works perfectly!

I think it's very interesting that administrator of a domain can act on behalf of a user (once we have given permission) with some of the documents of the organization but have been created by the user.

Also user resources (docs, spreadsheet, ...) so that a program can access (running with administrator permissions) without requiring the attention (or you do not have enough expertise) of the user, such as copies of security, ...

In my case, I make a program to evaluate a Google Docs form has been created by a user (a teacher) as does the gadget "Flubaroo" but in a graphical environment (GUI) programmed by Google Sites with Google Apps Script (GAS).

Thanks again for your time.

Sergi