# Get file permissions list in Google Shared Drive with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to get folder and file permissions which is located in Shared Drive. All I can get is permissions list for root Shared Drive but trying to run below code on any ID of file or folder inside throw error.

**Relavant Facts**

1. We are using Google Workspace Business Plus subscription
2. I am domain superadmin
3. I have access to this file in Shared Drive but I expect to have access to every file as an domain admin.
4. Right now I'm calling the below script from web IDE of Apps Script so it is working in my grant scope.
5. I am the script owner
6. Script is on My rive

**Script**

```
function getPermissions_(driveFileID, sharedDriveSupport){
  var thisDrivePermissions = Drive.Permissions.list(
    driveFileID,
    {
      useDomainAdminAccess: USE_DOMAIN_ADMIN_ACCESS,
      supportsAllDrives: sharedDriveSupport
    } 
  );
  return thisDrivePermissions;
}
```

**Errors**

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.list failed with error: Shared drive not found: xxxxxxxx
```

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.list failed with error: File not found:
```

How can I get the file permissions list in Google Shared Drive with Apps Script?

Comment: Do you have access to that particular folder or Drive file with the account that you are using to run the API?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (are using a Google Workspace account? are you the domain admin? Are you able to see the Shared Drive in the Google Drive user interface? How do you get the parameter values? how is the function being called? Are you the script owner ? Is the script in a shared Drive?)

Comment: @Rubén I have added answers to your questions

Comment: Thanks Mistic92. Please don't add labels as "Edit" / "Update". If you need to divide your post content add an horizontal line (i.e. you might use HTML tag `<hr>`) or add headings. When adding new content, add it thinking on first time readers, ...and people with bad memory like me :)

Answer (score 1):

As superadminin you don't have access to all files by default through Google Drive user interface / Google Apps Script. In order to get access to all files in your domain throught Apps Script you have to make use of *domain-wide deletegation of authority*.

The "not found" errors might occur because the file or shared drive ids are wrong or you don't have access, do double check that the ids are correct and that you passing the parameters correctly. For this you could use Logger.log
/ console.log to print the variable values to the execution log or use the Apps Script debugger.

Related

- [How to add a Google Drive folder to "My Drive" section to other users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12958382/1595451)
- [Take ownership of other users Drive-files using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23783735/1595451)

Comment: Yes, this might be the way! GAM tool is using domain-wide delegation so now I need to find a way to use it in Apps Script

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to list all the permissions that a drive file contained in a folder from a shared drive has. To do that, you may check the following script as an example:

```
function myFunction() {
  var driveFileID = "FILE ID";
  var sharedDriveSupport = true;
  var request = {
      "supportsAllDrives": sharedDriveSupport,
      "useDomainAdminAccess": true,
      "fields": "permissionIds"
    };

  var permissionsRequest = {
      "supportsAllDrives": sharedDriveSupport,
      "fields": "role"
    };
  var permissionsIDs = Drive.Files.get(driveFileID, request);
  
  for(var i=0; i<permissionsIDs.permissionIds.length; i++)
  {
    Logger.log((Drive.Permissions.get(driveFileID, permissionsIDs.permissionIds[i], permissionsRequest)).role);
  }
}
```

This is how it would display the information, by listing all the permission types from the specified file:

[image]

Note that this works because you mentioned you have access to the shared drive, however as [Rubén](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1595451/rub%c3%a9n) [mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74222794/) Google Workspace admins do not have access to all the files, just to the ones that are shared with them, and if you want to have access you can do it using domain wide delegation and user impersonation.

References:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [Permissions: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/get)

Comment: It's better to add execution logs as text.... use images only when it's needed to show how a user interface looks. When making reference to another post, it's nice to include a link as the number of answers an their order could change over the time. By the way, thanks for the mention

Comment: @Rubén you are completely right! Will make sure to add it that way next time, thanks for the advise!